# Transferring a file from my android device to my computer when USB is connected?

Tags: java, android, file-transfer

I'm now writing a project on android and my program must able to transfer / replace a file to my computer with certain address to sync my app with my app on my computer and reverse (from PC to device) only by pressing a single button in my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save file from android device to windows programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608893/save-file-from-android-device-to-windows-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Use http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports to forward a TCP/IP connection over the USB cable. Your app on the phone can act as a TCP server and receive arbitrary commands.

The downside of this solution is that you have to bundle the adb executable with your program and the user must have the proper drivers installed (that means mass-storage connection is not enough). The sources for adb are available, if you want.